# Converting Assemble - Trying to convert this assembly code into c code

Tags: assembly, mips

Trying to do this question but I don't know how, in this case, you would write out $s0 = everything:

Assume that the variables g, h, i, and j are assigned to registers $s1, $s2, $s3, and $s4, respectively
in the code given below. Assume that the base address of the array A is in register $s5.

```
Code:
addi $s0, $s1, -4
add $s0, $s0, $s2
add $s0, $s0, $s3
sub $s0, $s0, $s4
sw $s0, 24($s5)
```

For the MIPS assembly instructions above, what is the corresponding C statement?

Comment: Which part is causing you problem? That is just a bunch of additions and subtractions with a final array write.

Comment: Start by breaking each instruction. `addi $s0, $s1, -4` becomes `$s0 = $s1 + -4`. Repeat for the other instructions. Then use algebra.

Comment: I understand the addition and subtraction, but how do I actually write it out in assembly?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to write the solution as a C statement?

Answer (score 0):

If you substitute the variables into something pseudo C, using s0 so $s0:

```
s0 = g-4
s0 = s0 + h
s0 = s0 + i
s0 = s0 - j
A[6] = s0
```

Index of 6 is  using a word size of 32 (4 bytes) so 24/4

So, replacing s0:

```
A[6] = g - 4 + h + i - j;
```